# For loop while rename and move files withing a folder

Tags: powershell

Good morning,

started last week using powershell for some small scripts and now I'm stucked at creating a for loop for rename and move files. 
I've got these 2 commands

```
get-childitem "$Quellordner" | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.Replace("[Index]","-")}
get-childitem "$Quellordner" | Move-Item -Force -Destination $Zielordner -Verbose *>&1 | Set-Content $Logfileordner$Logfilename
```

and they are working fine but it's a bit odd not using a for loop for this. Unfortunately I can't get it to work :/

Any help will be appreciated!

(PS: Is there an other way to create a descending log file (newest to oldest) than copy the actual content and paste it belowe the new line?)

Comment: It's not clear what is your issue.

Comment: I would like to combine both commands within a for loop (or at least I would do it like this in Visual Basic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the rename and move by simply extending the pipeline:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path *.txt |
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace "[Index]","-"} -PassThru |
        Move-Item -Destination $Zielordner -Force
```

Writing to the start of a file is not directly supported, likely because it is an expensive operation (you need to move everything along somehow to make room), and seems like it will be more prone to corruption/data loss.  One thing to look at is writing to the log as normal, but *displaying* it in reverse order.  For example, `Get-Content` can read the individual lines of a text file into an array, which could easily be output from the end to the start.

Comment: @Moritz One snag with this: Because the string to replace contains the `[` character, you should **escape** that character if you are doing a regular expression `-replace`. Use `$_.Name -replace [regex]::Escape('[Index]'), "-"` instead.

Comment: @Theo.  Good point - I didn't actually test it with the strings here, I just copied them from the original post after using some simpler ones to double-check the syntax :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're actually already using a `foreach` loop. `ForEach-Object` to be precise.

Your line of code:

```
get-childitem "$Quellordner" | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.Replace("[Index]","-")}
```

does exactly the same as the following code does:

```
$files = get-childitem "$Quellordner"
foreach($_ in $files){
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.Replace("[Index]","-")}
}
```

About your PS: there is no way, I know of, to add a new line at the top of a text file without reading the file, adding the line you want to add at the top and write it back.